# Google storage: is there a region bucket in Germany?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, region, bucket

[Disclaimer: first post, so please excuse me if the question is not properly formulated]

Given the recent local "Datenschutz" (Privacy) laws in Germany, does anyone know whether Google Storage provides an option to guarantee storage inside Germany, with a specific regional bucket, like e.g. AWS does (location in Frankfurt)?

Comment: On their website, [they list (all?) data centers](http://www.google.com/about/datacenters/gallery/#/locations). Belgium seems to be the nearest.

Comment: this question is properly formulated, however, SO is not the right place for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, no. There is not currently a regional bucket option for Germany.

You can see a current list of regional bucket offerings here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/regional-buckets